# Android Button in Gridlayout don't have same margin top

Tags: android, android-button, android-gridlayout

I got a GridLayout, and there will be two or more buttons in the layout, and all the buttons must with same width.
My problem is that when the buttons having different line number of text, the marginTop of button will different too.
How can I fix this?
Thanks.

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid_buddies"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="TEST"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TESTDDFF"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Here is the picture:

[image]

Comment: You can change the text size of button so that it can be fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"` attribute in your Button with text `TEST`

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid_buddies"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
       android:layout_width="60dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:text="TEST"
       android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"/>
    <Button
       android:layout_width="60dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="TESTDDFF"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Now I will try translate this into programmaticaly.

Comment: Oh, no...I think the LayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL is not working.