# Buttons and ToggleButtons not lining up

Tags: java, android, android-button, android-gridlayout, android-togglebutton

I am adding a button and toggle button side by side into a gridlayout programmatically. My problem is these buttons aren't lining up.

Relevant code :

```
tempBtn = new Button(getActivity());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        scrnWidth/2, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.weight = 0.5f;
tempBtn.setLayoutParams(params);
tempBtn.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
```

Same code for a toggle button. The gridlayout is inside a relativelayout. I have tried all kinds of variations of layout params aswell as trying different ways of using weigths, none of it has worked. If I don't set the width the buttons are more closely lined up, but still not 100% and I do need these to be half the screen each.

Comment: the child View type should be irrelevant for the layout — try doing it with simple `View` first (give them different background colors). if everything is OK, then you probably have some issues with margins/padding of child views.

Comment: When I add two normal buttons next to each other they line up perfectly or two toggle buttons next to each other line up perfectly. So ill take a look at the margins/paddings.

Comment: Changing around the margins has had no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution in this question : [Android Button in Gridlayout don't have same margin top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644203/android-button-in-gridlayout-dont-have-same-margin-top?rq=1)

Just changed

```
tempBtn.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
```

to

```
tempBtn.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL);
```